# Definition for convexity for a function defined by cartisian product

Tags: calculus

I was wondering what is the definition of convexity for a function defined by cartisian product.
I know that if $f: R^n \rightarrow R$ is a convex function, then $f(sx+(1-s)y) \leq sf(x) + (1-s)f(y)$ for $s \in [0,1]$, what if we define a function $g(x,y)$, what is the definition of convexity for this kind of function?

Answer (score 0):

$$g(s x_1 + (1-s) x_2, s y_1 + (1-s) y_2) \le s g(x_1, y_1) + (1-s) g(x_2, y_2) \ \text{for}\ s \in [0,1]$$

Sometimes this is called "jointly convex" to distinguish this from "separately convex" (i.e. convex in $x$ for fixed $y$ and convex in $y$ for fixed $x$).